# Cant boot to EFI shell Asus Motherboard

Tags: motherboard, shell, secure-boot

I have an Asus Maximus VIII Impact MotherBoard

I just purchased an Intel RS3UC080 RAID card, and notice the firmware was very out of date. I figured I would update it before using the card. To do this you have to boot to an EFI shell. The README intel gives you in the download says to copy the files to a USB drive, then boot to the EFI shell on the drive. When I did that I got the following error

```
The Secure Boot is enabled to prevent untusted operating systems from
loading during the system start-up. To launch the EFI shell, please disable 
the secure boot option.
```

So I disabled secure boot by removing the platform key (the internet told me to), I can get it back.

after a reboot it shows that secure boot is disabled.

However I get the same error when I try to boot to the EFI Shell.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the platform key (PK) actually entered what's known as *setup mode,* in which Secure Boot variables may be altered at will. That's not quite identical to simply turning off Secure Boot. I would expect that either approach would work for doing what you wanted, but different UEFIs are subtly different, so maybe yours is weird in this way.

I recommend you re-enter your firmware and look for two options:

- **Re-load standard keys** -- This option should load the standard key set, including the PK and all other Secure Boot keys. This should effectively undo what you've just done. Note that there's *no* standardization of user interfaces for how to perform tasks like this, so you may need to go poking around to find the correct option.
- **Disable Secure Boot** -- This is a less destructive option than the one you used. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) for several examples of how to disable Secure Boot, including one on an ASUS board. (That said, my ASUS board is rather old as Secure Boot goes, and its user interface is not guaranteed to resemble yours'.)

With any luck, this will get you going.